# How to get column value of selected row

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I have bootstrap table with columns `id`, `name`, `description`, `author` and `date`.

Like this: `<b-table dark bordered striped hover responsive :fields="fields" :items="items" @row-clicked="$router.push({path: 'edit_category'})"></b-table>`

So i whant to get `id` column value of selected row and put it `@row-clicked="$router.push({path: 'edit_category', query:{id:`**here**`})"`

Comment: I would suggest to avoid using `row-clicked` event for navigation. screen reader users (and potentially keyboard only users) will not understand that the row is a link. It still has a `role="row"` (not link or button).  I would suggest actually placing a link (`router-link` or `b-link` or `b-button` with a `to` prop) in a scoped slot field cell. It will make your app much more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it :

```
<b-table :fields="fields" 
         :items="items" 
         @row-clicked="$router.push({path: 'edit_category',query:{id:$event.id}})"
></b-table>
```